# Syntax Error while adding TrustedHosts

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, winrm, windows

I have a machine that has Windows Server 2012 R2 installed on it. I just installed RSAT on my ThinkPad Tablet which runs Windows 8.1. I'm trying to add my server in the client's trusted host list with -

`winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts=”MyServer”}`

But getting the error message that says -

`Syntax error: input must be of the form {key ="value"[;key="value"]}`

I ran into the same issue while I was trying this same thing on my desktop machine, but somehow I fixed it and I cannot remember exactly how. Only difference is my desktop machine runs 64bit Windows 8.1 and my tablet runs 32bit Windows 8.1.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you copied a command from a website, then the double quotes are probably the wrong character. If you copy the command into Notepad (font = Lucida Console), you'll be able to notice the difference between command-line compatible double quotes and formatted/stylized quotes that will fail. I just spent 30min figuring this out then remembered I had the same problem years ago...

Comment: I typed the command on Command Prompt with Admin privilege :(

Answer (score 0):

Documentation suggests using single quotes around the argument

`winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputer"}'`

Comment: On my Desktop machine to make it work I never had to put those single quotes. But I'll try it and let you know. Can you please give a link of the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

Comment: Nope. Just tried with single quotes. It says `Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help`.